# Why property of button is 'undefined' in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping `button` from array:

```
render() {
        var replyList = questions.map(reply => {
            return (
                reply.r.map(singleReply => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <button
                                key={singleReply.id}
                                value={singleReply.b}
                                goto={singleReply.t}
                                onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
                                {singleReply.b}
                            </button>
                         </div>
                    );
                })
            );
        });
```

After `onClick` is called method:

```
onButtonClick = (evt) => {
        const btn = evt.target;
        this.setState(
            {
                currentDialog: btn.goto
            }
        );
        console.log(`The user clicked ${btn.value}`);
        console.log(`New state will be ${btn.goto}`);
    };
```

And I am receiving in console:

```
The user clicked reply1-2 App.js:25
New state will be undefined
```

My array looks like:

```
{
        id: uuid.v4(),
        q: 'dialog1',
        r: [
            { b: 'reply1-1', t: 1, id: uuid.v4() },
            { b: 'reply1-2', t: 2, id: uuid.v4() },
            { b: 'reply1-3', t: 3, id: uuid.v4() },
            { b: 'reply1-4', t: 4, id: uuid.v4() }
        ]
    },
(...)
```

As you can see, the problem is, that `value` property is rendered properly, but `goto` property is not receiving number from the array, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set custom *attribute* `goto`, however later you try to access `goto` *property*. Remember that *property* is not the same as *attribute*, as DOM attribute not necessarily sets corresponding property to `HTMLElement`. For some of them this is a case (`value`, `name`, `checked`, etc.) but for custom ones it's not.

If you really want to use custom attribute you should access it as an attribute:

```
console.log(`New state will be ${btn.getAttribute('goto')}`);
```

But in general, passing data via custom attributes is not a very good idea. At least you should use data attributes for this.

Also take a look at this [doc page](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html).

Comment: I had no idea about that, thanks. For updating the state I used not: `currentDialog: btn.getAttribute('goto')`.

Answer (score 0):

this.setState is asynchronous so you would have to update your state like this with callback -

```
  this.setState({ 
    currentDialog: btn.goto
    },() => {
      console.log(`New state will be ${btn.goto}`);
    });
```

Comment: In console still I am getting: `New state will be undefined` and `Object { currentDialog: 0, questions: (4) […] }` for `console.log(this.state);`